# Why is my async/await implementation not wokring?

Tags: typescript, csv

I have a list of csv-files and want to parse them. For this I imported [fast-csv](https://c2fo.github.io/fast-csv/).
I tried to implement the functionality as described in another  [stack overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64968247/node-js-fast-csv-synchronously-read-file-and-return-array).

But in my code it does not work, and I am really confused why it does not work.
I always get an empty array as output for `log(data)`.

```js
import { ParserOptionsArgs, parseFile } from '@fast-csv/parse'
import fs from 'fs'
import path from 'path'

var files: string[] = []
fs.readdirSync(inArg).forEach((file) => {
  files.push(path.parse(file).name)
})

files.forEach( async(file) => {
    const data: any = await readCsv(`${inArg}/${file}.csv`, { headers: true }, (row) => {})
    log(data)
    // here I want make some useful with the data
})

function readCsv(path: string, options: ParserOptionsArgs | undefined, rowProcessor: (arg0: any) => any) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    const data: any = []

    parseFile(path, options)
      .on('data', (row: any) => {
        const obj = rowProcessor(row)
        if (obj) {
          data.push(obj)
          log(obj)
        }
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        resolve(data)
        log('Done')
      })
  })
}
```

The console output:

```
Files: [ 'test1', 'test2', 'test3', 'test4' ]
Done
[]
Done
[]
Done
[]
Done
[]
```

May someone can help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `async/await` code is fine. **BUT:**  You are passing a `rowProcessor` function of

```
(row) => {}
```

to your `readCsv`. This `rowProcessor` doesn't return anything. I know it's a subtle pitfall, I stumbled upon this more than once. But how it's written above, the `{}` does not define an object, but an empty function body. If you really intend to return an empty object your `rowProcessor` should be

```
(row) => { return {}; }
```

or

```
(row) => ({})
```

Now, as your rowprocessor doesn't return anything, in the following snippet

```
const obj = rowProcessor(row)
if (obj) {
  data.push(obj)
  log(obj)
}
```

`obj` will of course always be `undefined` thus, nothing is pushed to your `data` array and hence `log(data)` will log the empty array, we see.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's the problem when you take over stackoverflow snippets of things you don't really understand yet. I have now just removed the `rowProcessor` completely and return the `row` directly because I don't need it and it does exactly as I expected.